# How to enqueue old messages into a new queue in RabbitMQ Exchange?

Tags: rabbitmq

I have an exchange with a type of `topic` that only redirects messages to queue `payments`

Somewhere in the future, I will decide to add another queue `payment_analyze` to analyze all old and new messages that have been enqueued.

durable exchanges and queues survive rabbit MQ restarts, persistent messages get written to disk but when binding a new queue to an old durable exchange, old messages do not get redirected (only new ones do get redirected)

From my understanding, this is the intended behavior as exchanges do not store messages and only act as a "proxy"

How do I achieve this?

**Possible Solution**

Creating a queue named `parking` and adding every enqueued message to it, whenever a new queue is added, consume messages from `parking` without acknowledging to keep the new queue "semi" up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though your configured persistent messages on the `payments` queue, this just means messages will survive a broker restart - once a message has been consumed and acknowledged it would be removed.

If you know you're going to need the `payment_analyze` queue at some point in the future, is it viable to just create this queue/binding upfront and route messages to both `payment_analyze` and `payments`? Messages on the `payment_analyze` will bank up until you're ready to start consuming them. Note: If you're producing a large number of messages this approach might result in storage issues...

As an alternative, you could write the messages to BLOB storage (or some other data store) as part of your `payments` queue consumer (or a different queue/consumer altogether) and then when you're ready to introduce the `payment_analyze` queue, you could write a script to read all the old messages from BLOB storage and send them to the RabbitMQ exchange. With 'topic' exchanges - see [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-dotnet.html) - you can probably be clever with wildcards and routing keys in your queue bindings to ensure both old messages (from BLOB storage) as well as new messages are both routed to the `payment_analyze` queue, but only new messages are routed to the `payments` queue (so that your `payments` queue consumer is not reprocessing old messages).

Another option (assuming you're not overly invested in RabbitMQ) could be to consider Apache Kafka instead which deals with this scenario quite nicely as messages aren't automatically removed from a partition once they've been processed by a subscriber.

Anyways, just a few options to consider...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the well-detailed answer. I am actually coming from Kafka and unfortunately, Kafka is not affordable for us right now (both in terms of deployment knowledge and expenses)